# Chaining conditional probabilities - does p(a|b)*p(b|c)=p(a|c)?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I heard that $P(A|B)P(B|C)=P(A|C)$ but cannot reproduce this (for the general case).Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal that you couldn't because it's not correct. Let $A=B'$. Then $P(A|B)=0$, which means $P(A|B)P(B|C)=0$, but the RHS is still $P(A|C)=P(B'|C)$, which is not necessarily $0$.

Comment: What if $P(A|B,C)\neq 0$? Then we have $P(A|C)=P(A|B,C)P(B)$ and $P(A|B)P(B|C)= P(A|B,C)P(B)P(B|C)=P(A|B,C)P(B)$. So the equality holds, right? Correct me if there is something wrong.

Comment: How did you come up with $P(A|C)=P(A|B,C)P(B)$?

Comment: I found it here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440993/does-pab-cpb-pac

Comment: There, several answers state that it's not correct in general.